# how to run non-installed(portable) application using linux terminal

Tags: linux, eclipse, terminal

I'm new to Linux and i use Kali Linux. I downloaded the eclipse ide. Every time, when i need to run it, i should navigate to eclipse folder and run the eclipse file. there are other softwares like pycharm have the same issue.
If there's any method to run these programs just typing "eclipse" or "pycharm" on terminal (like firefox, atom) it's very helpful. If anyone know how to do it please let me know. I already searched a solution for this problem and i couldn't find any solution.
-Thanks (sorry for my English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your ~/.bashrc  and  add the PATH of your application(you use PATH rather then CONFIG_PATH)

export PATH=$PATH:/path/to_directory_containing_program
export CONFIG_PATH=/my_path_to_PROGRAM/PROGRAM/config/

- Another solution is Create a shorcut in your desktop

Comment: this worked perfectly fine with eclipse. thank you so much  for that. but in pycharm, it has a pycharm.sh file(in pycharm/ bin) and it has no config directory . I tried above method but it didn't work. any advices? -thanks

Comment: i just create a Shortcut of pycharm like this command  "/opt/pycharm-community/bin/pycharm.sh# %f  
so is working for me , just find  the pycharm.sh in your path

Answer (score 0):

Go to `cd /usr/local/bin` (or `cd /usr/bin`) and do:
`sudo ln -s /path/to/eclipse` where `eclipse` is the binary that you are used to launch.

`/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin` directories should already be in your PATH, so you don't need to modify ~/.bashrc.